# Steps to Upgrade the leaflet map library

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

i have mentioned below library paths in index.html in my application i want to upgrade both map and leaflet libraries to new versions.so please help,
1. what are the libraries i need to add
2. is there any of below library paths replaceble

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
```

and

```
<script src="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.js"></script>
    <script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking. Are you asking if there are new versions of these libraries available? If so, yes - you would google for the library name, like [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/) and see that version 2.2.1 is available, and the code to include the new version is prominently featured on that page.